# Custom domain name for AWS RDS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-rds

What possible ways to translate entry point like my-name.ck4k21dvamqbq9.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com:5432 to db.domain.com?

For own instances we use map in /etc/hosts based on private ip. Storing long entry point name a little bit confusing, and must be maintained in a lot of settings files.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Add a CNAME record in your DNS for `db.example.com` that points to your RDS endpoint (without the port, i.e. `my-name.ck4k21dvamqbq9.eu-west-1.rds.amazonaws.com`).

Comment: Doing this will often cause a failure in TLS/SSL verification which is bad and should be avoided.